# favorite button dynamic changing the name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

on each post page has a button to "like" how can I check if the post was liked and change the button name, for example, "liked" and if not, by clicking the button would be done, but everything in the background, I have very shallow knowledge of javascript, but I know I'll need ajax for it. already set up a small script in php / mysql that returns a json `{ "favorite": 1}` when the post is already liked or changes to liked, and its natural state is `{ "favorite": 0}`

Because you can only like the post being logged into the site, the ***user id*** will be set by **session**, and the ***id of the post*** will be sent using the **POST** method

Ex:

```
<a href="site.com/post/like"> Favorite </a>
```

... Sorry for my bad english

Comment: will you post the code?

Comment: the code that i basically gonna make is the PHP part, that checks if the post had already been liked , and if dont, just insert it on the db, and returns the json with 1 or 0, i just need to do that with ajax, wich i dont know how...

Comment: The ajax call AND the PHP script returning `{ "favorite": 1}` is not done ?

Comment: you mean the code you had posted? but, it dont has the request if the favorite was 0, got it?

Comment: i want to verify if the json was 1 or 0 to handle it, if it was 1 just change the name of the button, but if its not, i insert into the db and then return 1 and changes the name, and i also can "dislike" it.

Comment: Can you just show what you have so far ? Because if you have absolutely nothing except a worpress set up and an empty link... It sounds like a resquest to code the entire solution for you. Show the json creation part... If this is all you have.

Comment: actually im not using Wordpress, its a little MVC application just for studying, but i havent the PHP part yet, but i can handle it, its basically checking if exists and insert/ update into the db, just like the facebook "like" button,

Comment: @mplungjan's answer is then a better start for you. It is applying the 0/1 status to the link on post page load... And on the like button click, it ajax calls a `likeornot.php` that you will have to do to store the value in DB. You talked about ""dislike" too... And, I'm sure you will want to "count" the likes and dislikes... Franckly, this is not an easy one. And I think your question is a bit too wide for a single question on SO. I'll remove my answer, since it is not relevant anymore.

Comment: it is simple that it looks, i dont mind to count the likes/dislikes, it's like a option to bookmark a post as favorite into the user account, try to think it without the ajax part, verifying and insert/update into the db normally with a page refresh

Comment: i gonna make a php script and post here later, think its gonna clarify all

Answer (score 1):

1. set the status on the server I am assuming the status is in the $favorite var 
   `<a id="1234" href="site.com/post/like"`
   `class="like <?PHP echo $favorite?"liked":""; ?>">Favorite</a>`
2. call when clicked

like this

```
$(function() {
  $(".like").on("click",function() { 
    $.post("likeornot.php?id="+this.id,function(data) {
      $(this).toggleClass("liked",data.favorite==1);
      // you can set the html of the link here too
    });
});
```